# Как организовать поочередное воспроизведение через YouTube API?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, youtube-api

Мне очень понравилось как на [moodfuse.com](http://moodfuse.com) организованы плейлисты.

Т.е. выбираем жанр — попадаем на страницу с плейлистом и видим список с 10-20 наименований. Нажимаем на любой из них — появляется слева видеоролик с YouTube, и после его окончания открывается следующий (по списку).

Как отображать видеоролик с нужной песней — я понимаю. Но я не могу понять, как организовано поочередное воспроизведение?

Answer (score 1):

Для поочередного воспроизведения прослушивают событие OnStateChange. Плеер создается примерно так:

```
var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
```

Есть функция, которая обрабатывает это событие:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
      // запускаем следующее видео
    }
}
```

Comment: а как мне задать список ключей для воспроизведения, что бы JS понимал, какой после какого воспроизводить?

Comment: Никак, только программно. Считывайте справа список файлов, ищите в нем тот, что закончил воспроизводиться, берите id следующего и запускайте

Comment: понял. Подскажите пожалуйста по подробнее, как определить, что видео закончилось и нужно воспроизвести следующее по списку?

Comment: Я все написал в ответе. Когда видео закончится, YouTube API создаст событие OnStateChange и вызовет вашу функцию onPlayerStateChange()